# WordPress endpoint creation - Callback with string passes quotes

Tags: php, json, endpoint

I am creating an endpoint myurl.com/wp-json/userid/user/, to which my Android app will make requests, in order to get the user id by username.

See the code below:

```
        add_action('rest_api_init', 'get_user_id');
    function get_user_id(){
        register_rest_route('userid/','user/(?P<string>.+)', array(
            'methods' => GET,
            'callback' => 'get_this_id',
            'args' => [ 'string' ]));
    }

    function get_this_id($data){
        $username = $data['string'];            
        $myObj = get_user_by('username', $username);            
        $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
        echo $myJSON;
    }
```

What happens is that the get_this_id function, gets "username" instead of plain username, so the get_user_by('username', $username) function does not work.

For example instead of taking **get_user_by('username', admin)** it gets **get_user_by('username', "admin")**.

How can I make sure that I get totally rid of the quotes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with quotes? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on WP documentation, endpoint need version `userid/v1` and `methods` value is a string `GET`. Response callback function doesn't need to convert to JSON, WP automatick detect format and converted (Array/Object).

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'get_user_id');
function get_user_id()
{
    register_rest_route('userid/v1', 'user/(?P<string>.+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_this_id',
        'args' => ['string']
    ));
}

function get_this_id($data)
{
    $username = $data['string'];
    $user = get_user_by('login', $username);
    return $user;
}
```

Example URL:
`domain.tld/wp-json/userid/v1/user/parsa`

Comment: If this answers the question, please explain how. Telling someone to read documentation, followed by a wall of code, is not very helpful.

Comment: Omg respect man! Thanks for the quick answer, this worked perfectly and now it's quite time I get a rest at last! :D